# Linux: when does the "system" system call return 1

Tags: linux, system-calls

From [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/system.html) man page i see that the exit status will be a value that's returned from the shell by calling exit(127) or _exit(127), means that the value is always more than 127?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you were paying attention when you read that page...

Comment: Well it does say this too:

If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter in the format specified by waitpid(). The termination status shall be as defined for the sh utility; otherwise, the termination status is unspecified.

In my case the buffer i gave it to the 'system' system call is a valid one and contains a valid data always.

Comment: Well i got it, seems to be the NULL thingy as arg to the system call, now i have to figure why its coming that way ;-). Sorry to bother you guys...